# Visualforce table column headers of headers

Tags: visualforce, table

Apologies for the confusing title.

How would I go about making a table structured similarly to the following image, in a visualforce page? I've seen answers to similar questions mentioning facets but I'm not sure how that would work when I want to group some headers...

[image]

Where ROW 1 WITH DATA is constructed in the typical repeat of an apex:pageBlockTable (i.e. from an sObject data). "Other header", "header group", "A", and "B" are all column headers and should not effect the row generation.

Is it possible to do this using solely an apex:pageBlockTable and not an html table? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very first [link from my google results](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098BqIAI) has it all:

```
<apex:facet name="header">
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" rowspan="2">Other header</td>
            <td colspan="2">header group</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">A</td>
            <td width="25%">B</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</apex:facet>
```

Comment: right-o - when faced with complex layout; use straight HTML, debug that and then apply VF markup

Comment: This worked but not as well as I would have liked it to.  I'm going to revert to changing the structure of the table to avoid having to do this.  Thanks though!

Comment: Depending on your use case, you can take a look at [datatables plug-in for the jQuery library](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html) - it has a lot of customization options and very popular.